# Expandable text fields in PDF Forms, with Adobe Acrobat

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I think this should be a relatively straightforward question to answer: is it possible in Adobe Acrobat only (not LiveCycle) to create text fields/boxes which automatically expand with their text? Scrollbars are not what we're looking for; the box itself must expand so that all the text is printable, as well as be saveable, printable and accessible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Propaganda would say, this is not possible, and you will need XFA/LiveCycle Designer to do it.

It is possible, and I had it in practical use in some forms (not anymore, because they completely changed their forms system). It is "a little bit messy", and it only works with growing, but not with shrinking (although there may be some more fiddling needed to make it possible).

There is another alternative, which could work, if some tolerance is given to the precision. In this alternative, we count characters and line breaks, and change the size of the field accordingly.

Finally, the cheapass solution would be setting the font size to automatic, and let it change so that the contents fits into the field.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think the question had an implied "If it's possible, how?" So how is it done?

Comment: @Max Wyss, Could you pleas explain how I can do this?

Comment: Shrinking the text does not imply expanding text forms although it would work as a solution for some I don't see it working for my project. I do like the solution regarding counting characters and line breaking just not sure how to implement that.

Comment: @GeorgeGarey You let the user enter whatever, and in the Format event, you will use event.value, and analyze it. Then you would (re)calculate the coordinates of the field and set them with the event.target.rect property. A good approximation for the number of characters per line is the number of "n" you can put into one line of your field.

Comment: @MaxWyss I will try creating a script dynamically with javascript that auto adjusts the text fields i'm just not sure how to start.